# Gstreamer with two Udpsinks

Tags: gstreamer, live-streaming

I like to know how to receiver Gstreamer Live video Streaming which has dual udpsink on the Receiver sides.

Here i provide single Udpsink transmitter and receiver which works absolutely fine

**Sender** :  *"raspivid -t 999999 -h 480 -w 640 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc fd=0 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.105 port=5000"*

**Receiver** : *"udpsrc port=5000 caps=application/x-rtp buffer-size=100000 ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! queue ! autovideosink sync=false"*

**Dual Udpsink Sender**: *raspivid -t 999999 -h 480 -w 640 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc fd=0 ! tee name=tp \tp. h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.105 port=5000 \tp. ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.100 port=5005*

Now i am unable to receiver on anyone of the receiver side.. Please any help me.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use a single multiudpsink element instead:

> raspivid -t 999999 -h 480 -w 640 -fps 25 -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-0.10 -v fdsrc fd=0 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! multiudpsink clients=192.168.0.105:5000,192.168.0.100:5005